# RealsSence Camera using OpenCV does not save video file

Tags: python, opencv, realsense

I am using the Intel RealSence D415 Camera and this python code to start it:

```
import pyrealsense2 as rs
import numpy as np
import cv2 

pipeline = rs.pipeline()
pipeline.start()
config = rs.config()
config.enable_stream(rs.stream.color, 640, 360, rs.format.bgr8, 30)


while True:
    # Camera Start (external)-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    frames = pipeline.wait_for_frames()
    color_frame = frames.get_color_frame()
    # Convert images to numpy arrays
    color_image = np.asanyarray(color_frame.get_data())
    camera = cv2.VideoCapture(3)
    frame_width2 = int(camera.get(3))
    frame_height2 = int(camera.get(4))
    size2 = (frame_width2, frame_height2)
    result_camera = cv2.VideoWriter('NameAsDateTime_camera.avi', cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MJPG'), 10, size2)
    while(camera.isOpened()):
        ret_cam, frame_cam = camera.read()
        if ret_cam == True:
            result_camera.write(color_image)
            cv2.imshow("Camera", color_image)
            key_cam = cv2.waitKey(20) & 0xFF
```

Though it does start to record, it does not seem to save the file correctly. it seems like it only takes a picture of the first second and stores that picture as videofile. What did I do wrong?

Comment: `assert result_camera.isOpened()` and check that you give it frames the exact size that you promised in the constructor. also check data type and whatnot.

Comment: and how do i check that?

Comment: [tour], [ask], [mre] <- in the last link there's a link to a "how to debug programs" article.